# Local variable class is inserted in map but it works

Tags: c++11

I have a question on local class inserting to a `map`.
For testing I created a class in a function **without newing** so that the scope is in local.
Then I inserted the class as a value in a map. 
I thought then the class would be destroyed since the scope of the class is local. 
However it is showing the inserted value( which is 40 in below code). 
Is it that the OS has lazy delete on memory? My code is as follow

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyClass{
    public:
        MyClass(int id){m_id = id;};
        void PrintThis(){cout << " This is test "<< m_id << endl;};
        int m_id;
};

class Test{
    public:
        unordered_map<int, MyClass> mapTest2;
        void TestLocal(){
            MyClass mc1(10);
            MyClass mc2(20);
            MyClass mc3(30);

            mapTest2.insert(make_pair(1, mc1));
            mapTest2.insert(make_pair(2, mc2));
            mapTest2.insert(make_pair(3, mc3));

        }

        void TestLocal2(){
            MyClass mc1(40);
            MyClass mc2(50);
            MyClass mc3(60);

            mapTest2.insert(make_pair(4, mc1));
            mapTest2.insert(make_pair(5, mc2));
            mapTest2.insert(make_pair(6, mc3));
        }   
};   

int main(){
    Test* tt1 = new Test();
    tt1->TestLocal();
    tt1->TestLocal2();
    auto search2 = tt1->mapTest2.find(4);
    if(search2 != tt1->mapTest2.end()) {
        MyClass mc = search2->second;
        cout << mc.m_id << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "not Found2 " << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: In TestLocal, the instances of MyClass created are surely local and gets destroyed when it goes out of scope, but when you are inserting into the map, the instances gets copied. So, before the scope of the function ends, there are two copies of the same instance, one in the current scope and one inside the map. The copied instance will only get deleted once the instance of Test class gets out of scope or when deleted inside main in your case, since mapTest2 is a member of your class Test..

Comment: @Arunmu oh~ ok.. so it does something like memcpy inside unordered_map if my understanding is correct. Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't say memcpy, but just copy. What to use is completely dependent upon the compiler and the platform. For the sake of correctness, just saying copied is good enough :)

Comment: In fact, what it's calling is an implicitly generated _copy constructor_.  Add a manual copy constructor to your class, such as `MyClass(const MyClass& other) : m_id(other.m_id) { cout << "MyClass copy constructor called\n"; }` and you should see that being called.